# Product of Bernstein sets

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

Remember that a Bernstein set is a set
$B\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with the property that for any uncountable closed set, $S$, in the real line both
$B\cap S$ and $(\mathbb{R}\setminus B)\cap S$ are non-empty. Some known results are the following: Bernstein sets are Baire spaces, also the Banach-Mazur game played in a Bernstein set is indeterminate. My question is: if $B, D\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ are Bernstein sets then $B\times D$ is a Baire space?

Thanks

Comment: Every Bernstein set is second-countable (as is any subset of $\mathbb R$), so has a locally countable pseudo-basis. By Theorem 2 [here](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm49/fm49113.pdf), this implies $B\times D$ is a Baire space.

Comment: Thanks @Wojowu, I did not know that great result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There exist some general results which show when a product of Baire spaces is Baire. Specifically, Theorem 2 [here](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm49/fm49113.pdf) states

> If $X,Y$ are two Baire spaces and at least one has a *locally countable pseudo-base*, then $X\times Y$ is a Baire space.

A *pseudo-base* of a topological space $X$ is a family of nonempty open sets such that every open set in $X$ contains an element of the family. In particular, any base is a pseudo-base. A family is *locally countable* if any element of the family contains only countably many other ones. In particular, any countable family is locally countable.

Now, any Bernstein set, in fact any subset of a second countable space, is second-countable, which means it has a countable base, which is a locally countable pseudo-base. Therefore, by the theorem, a product of Bernstein sets is Baire.

It is worth noting that not every product of Baire spaces is Baire. Oxtoby (the author of the linked paper) constructs a Baire space whose square is not Baire assuming the continuum hypothesis. Cohen [has shown](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2041855?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) CH is not necessary for that

Comment: In fact, later using Cohen's idea (using stationary sets in $\omega_1$), were constructed two Baire metric spaces whose product is not Baire in ZFC. (Applications of stationary sets in topology - William G.Fleissner in Surveys in General Topology
1980, Pages 163-193)

Comment: "Weak basis" is also used (at least by Kechris) for pseudo-base.

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf Thanks for this remark. It seems that neither term is particularly standard though.

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf, I would say the most standard name is $\pi$-base.

Comment: In modern terminology a *pseudo-base* is a collection of open sets such that each singleton is the intersection of all elements of the family that contain it.

Comment: @RamirodelaVega Thank you. So pseudo-base now means something different? In a quick look this doesn't seem the same thing.